# What's the distance between the locations seen on Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, map

It's pretty clear that Rey depends on her speeder for her livelihood as a scavenger on Jakku.  The Star Destroyer that she's seen climbing through is clearly some significant distance away from Niima Outpost: she exits the ship at midday and it's almost sunset by the time she arrives at the outpost.  Her AT-AT home is much closer to the outpost than the ship but still farther than can be easily traveled on foot.  Also, Rey's home is close enough to the village of Tuanul that BB-8 was able to make it from there to the AT-AT in one night.

#### Do we have any solid information on exactly how far these four locations are from each other?

Answer (score 8):

There's a map in the new [Star Wars: Galactic Atlas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Galactic_Atlas) factbook. It is, alas, not to any sort of obvious scale, but it does at least show you where your four locations are in relation to each other.

As to why it took Rey so long to get back, you might want to note that she took a complete lap of a nearby attraction called "The Sitter", presumably looking for good salvage on her way back.

[image]

Comment: seems odd that Rey's speeder is positioned facing the Star Destroyer, as well as her implied direction (right to left) and that Rey and BB-8 are shown as walking together near the Star Destroyer - shouldn't Rey and BB-8 be near the  Luggabeast? What an odd map

Comment: @NKCampbell - I suspect that it's intended to be representative rather than to scale.

Comment: I'm not even talking so much about scale as positional accuracy

Comment: @NKCampbell Yes, you're right.  That dashed line completely contradicts the movie and is therefore non-canonical.

Comment: @Bob - Only the small pic of Rey and BB-8 contradict the film and there's no specific indication that they're intended to be anything other than decorative flair.